# Materialized View refresh fast is making golden gate Job to abend

Tags: oracle, performance, refresh, materialized-views

We created a materialized view with fast refresh on commit. We have seven  base tables for  MV and corresponding logs created too.  We have Golden Gate configured for replication on base tables. Due to load on MV Golden Gate job on base tables getting abended.

```
    create materialized view MV_SPON_PERMIT_RES
    refresh fast  on commit
    as
    SELECT 
    p.rowid p_rowid,
           pd.rowid pd_rowid,
           ep.rowid ep_rowid,
          tl.rowid tl_rowid,
         la.rowid la_rowid,
          ip.rowid ip_rowid,
           pp.rowid pp_rowid,
      on tableA,tableB,TableC
  union all
  p.rowid p_rowid,
           pd.rowid pd_rowid,
           ep.rowid ep_rowid,
          tl.rowid tl_rowid,
         la.rowid la_rowid,
          ip.rowid ip_rowid,
           pp.rowid pp_rowid
on tableX,tableY,tableZ
```

Problem: fast refresh on commit is making Golden Gate job abend:

```
DELETE FROM "VISION_INTG"."MV_SPON_PERMIT_RES" SNA$
WHERE "PP_ROWID" IN (SELECT/*+ NO_MERGE  HASH_SJ  */ *
                     FROM (SELECT CHARTOROWID ("MAS$"."M_ROW$$") RID$
                           FROM "VISION_INTG"."MLOG$test" "MAS$"
                           WHERE "MAS$".SNAPTIME$$ > :B_ST0) MAS$)
AND "FILE_TYPE" = 'Permit'
```

Please help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

If we are using Golden gate on replicating the data between layers then we cant use MV with refresh fast  commit. we  can go MV on demand which should refresh data in incremental way. If incremental way refresh is taking time then we need to check the system parameter.
_mv_refresh_use_stats

As per oracle documentation it should be set to false
alter system set "_mv_refresh_use_stats"=FALSE;